# Clearing using finings during racking prior to bottling - will there still be enough yeast for second fermentation?

Tags: secondary, kits, trub, finings

I am taking the opportunity to use the current situation to get brewing again. I'm only using kits at the moment, but plan to move to next stages soon. I currently have a Festival kit of Old Suffolk ale in primary and will be bottling early next week. I'd like to remove as much of the trub from the bottles as possible, and will probably use finings in the secondary before adding the priming sugar and bottling.  My question is two fold.

Firstly, if the finings work, won't I be left with some new trub in the bottom of the second bin, which will get mixed in when adding the sugar?

Secondly, if I get around that, will there be enough 'good' yeast in the beer to execute a successful second fermentation (this question was asked, but in a filtering context, not finings)

Comment: I haven't used commercial finings for ages. Instead, I use gelatine from the supermarket.
One tablespoon in a little water for two minutes in the microwave easily dissolves it.
Add this to the fermenter and in two days you will have a lovely clear beer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and yes.  Finings will generate trub, and you might want to rack the beer off it before packaging.  Finings also do not remove much if any of the yeast so priming will not be a problem at all whatsoever.  I've been bottling and using finings for many years and never had any problems with carbonation.

Comment: Most helpful. I have now received the finings so i can get on with the next stage. However, the packet only says to add the finings and 'store in a cool place to clear'. Any suggestions how long 5 gallons needs to clear?

Comment: Amount of time varies.  Often you will see good results within 48 hours, but occasionally it will take a week or two.  Peek inside after 2-3 days and you'll have a pretty good idea of how long it will take.

Comment: If you like my response, please upvote it.  :)